# send multipart data to server from android

Tags: android, server

I am new to android. i am working on multi part data. when we use HttPURLConnection to send data from android to server we set some Properties like..

```
       conn.setDoInput(true);
       conn.setDoOutput(true);
       conn.setUseCaches(false);
       conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
       conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
       conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
       conn.setRequestProperty("imagefile", img_file);
       conn.setRequestProperty("imagename", img_name);
```

i just want to know why we set these properties. specially last two. is it necessary to set??

Comment: yes @jenny, server can only find which type of data you send through this properties.

Comment: thank u elango... but without specifying these properties i can also upload image to server so what is the importance of these??